# making the image on a picturebox change when a specific name is selected from a listbox in C#

Tags: c#, listbox, picturebox

This is what I've found so far because my book doesn't have anything on PictureBoxes besides two little notes at the bottom of the page. The image in the box is ssupposed to be nothing in the beginning but as the user selects an item from lstBxBagType the image in the picture box should change into that specific item.

```
private void lstBxBagType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (this.lstBxBagType.Text == "Beaded-$45.00")
        pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\me\Desktop\Ch10As\Ch10As\Resources\BeadedBag.jpg");
    else if (this.lstBxBagType.Text == "Full Decorative-$50.00")
        pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\me\Desktop\Ch10As\Ch10As\Resources\FullDecoBag.jpg");
    else if (this.lstBxBagType.Text == "Pirate Design-$40.00")
        pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\me\Desktop\Ch10As\Ch10As\Resources\PirateBag.jpg");
    else if (this.lstBxBagType.Text == "Fringed-$25.00")
        pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\me\Desktop\Ch10As\Ch10As\Resources\FringedBag.jpg");
    else if (this.lstBxBagType.Text == "Leather-$80.00")
        pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\me\Desktop\Ch10As\Ch10As\Resources\LeatherBag.jpg");
    else if (this.lstBxBagType.Text == "Plain-$20.00")
        pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\me\Desktop\Ch10As\Ch10As\Resources\PlainBag.jpg");
}
```

ok so I just went back to look at the properties and changed it so that the image on the picture box changes to what selected when the picturebox is clicked but that's not how its supposed to be, how do i make it change automatically, im going to do some trial and error to see if i can find one to to that

Comment: What issues are you having with the code that you have posted, are you getting errors or is it functionally not doing what you are expecting?

Comment: it's not working I need to find how to fix it

Comment: your code is working for, me what specifically is it not doing for you?

Comment: It's not changing the picturebox image

Comment: have you put a breakpoint on your selectedIndexChanged eventhandler to make sure it is being run when you select your text?

Comment: as I said earlier you code will work, did you verify that your eventhandler for your `lstBxBagType_SelectedIndexChanged` event is being run by putting a breakpoint on it, then step through it to see if your text matches.

Comment: THe only one that changes the picturebox(that i can find) is the click on picturebox properties, am i not seeing one? Because my teacher's instructions said images were supposed to change automatically, not when you click on the picturebox?

Comment: go to your ListBox's Properties, click the lightning bolt to get to the events, look for the SelectedIndexChanged and verify that your handler is assigned to it.

Comment: I have that assigned to a textbox, but I can change it if I need to, but I don't see the PictureBox option

Comment: That needs to be assigned to your ListBox, not a TextBox and not the PictureBox.

Comment: I got it, when I tried to change the ListBox's properties it made

private void PictureBox1(object sender, EventArgs e)

and that's where I put the code and it worked. Thanks A Lot Everyone! I couldn't have done it without all the tips :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a ListBox, check against the SelectedItem() property, not the Text() property:

```
        if (lstBxBagType.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Beaded-$45.00")
        {
            // do something
        }
```

Comment: Agreed that would be the preferred way, but the Text property is the Text of the Currently selected Item. I think his problem is that he doesn't have his eventhandler hooked up correctly.